# Help calculating sum $\sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{2p}{k}\binom{2p}{2k}}{\binom{4p}{2k}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Does anyone know how can i calculate the value of this sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{2p}{k}\binom{2p}{2k}}{\binom{4p}{2k}}=2^{2p} \frac{((2p)!)^2}{(4p)!}$$

Comment: You may write down what you have tried so far so that people here may help you better.

Answer (score 2):

First multiply both sides by $\binom{4p}{2p}$ and do a little tinkering, so that the identity becomes

$$\begin{align*}
2^{2p}&=\sum_{k=0}^p(-1)^k\frac{(4p-2k)!}{k!(2p-k)!(2p-2k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^p(-1)^k\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^p(-1)^k\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2p}(-1)^k\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p}\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last step follows from the fact that $\binom{4p-2k}{2p}=0$ when $k>p$.

Now suppose that we have $2p$ pairs of shoes numbered from $1$ through $2p$, and we want to choose a set of $2p$ shoes by taking one shoe from each pair. Since we must choose either the left or the right shoe from each pair, there are $2^{2p}$ such sets of shoes.

On the other hand, we can use an [inclusion-exclusion argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) to count them. For $k\in[2p]$ let $A_k$ be the family of sets of $2p$ shoes (*not* $2p$ pairs of shoes) from the entire set of $4p$ shoes that do not contain either shoe from pair $k$. If $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[2p]$, then

$$\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\,\right|=\binom{4p-2|I|}{2p}\;,$$

so

$$\left|\,\bigcup_{k\in[2p]}A_k\,\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[2p]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\binom{4p-2|I|}{2p}=\sum_{k=1}^{2p}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p}\;.$$

This is the number of sets of $2p$ shoes that are disjoint from at least one of the $2p$ pairs and therefore contain both shoes from at least one pair. There are altogether $\binom{4p}{2p}$ sets of $2p$ shoes, so there are

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{4p}{2p}-\sum_{k=1}^{2p}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p}&=\binom{4p}{2p}+\sum_{k=1}^{2p}(-1)^k\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2p}(-1)^k\binom{2p}k\binom{4p-2k}{2p}
\end{align*}$$

sets of $2p$ shoes that contain exactly one shoe from each pair, and the identity is established.